# Fingerprint sensor + Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader

I did lsusb and it finds these:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b5f7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:3016 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5571 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Fit
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0c03 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think the fingerprint sensor `04f2:b5f7` is this one. But it wont get recognized. Is there any way I can ... enable it? Thanks! :)